# Why does SQL Server 2008 R2 generate crash dump files "*.mdmp"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have problem with my SQL Server 2008 R2, it generates crash dump files every short time, these files eat up space of `c:\` partition, it may exceed 20GB in `Microsoft SQL Server/MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER/MSSQL/Log`

**Edit**  : part of the log files

```
External dump process returned no errors.2012-12-23 17:14:39.96 spid16s    
ex_raise2:         Exception raised, major=52, minor=42, state=9, severity=22, attempting to create symptom dump

2012-12-23 17:14:39.96 spid16s     Using 'dbghelp.dll' version '4.0.5'
```

please help

Comment: Are there any accompanying error messages with these? (e.g. assertion failed)

Comment: Have you **looked** at the crash dump files and/or logs to find out what **causes** these crashes? You need to find (and fix!) the root cause .....

Comment: You have to open a [support case](http://support.microsoft.com/gp/support-options-for-business/en-us) with CSS and ask them to investigate the crash dumps.